# 'The parameter 'addresses' cannot be an empty string' with 2 messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtpclient

I'm trying to send 2 emails from the same codebehind, but it gives me this error:

> The parameter 'addresses' cannot be an empty string.

If I delete 1 of this message, it sends it without any problem... why?
This is my code:

```
MailMessage message;
string body;
SmtpClient sc;
message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("address@address.ext");
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.smtp.smtp");
sc.Port = 25;
sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("address@address.ext", "password");
sc.EnableSsl = true;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (s, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
message.To.Add("address@address.ext");
message.Subject = "This is the subject";

MailMessage message2;
string body2;
message2 = new MailMessage();
message2.From = new MailAddress("address@address.ext");
message2.IsBodyHtml = true;
message2.To.Add("address@address.ext");
message2.Subject = "This is the subject2";
body2 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("This is the body2");
message2.Body = body2;
sc.Send(message2);

body = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("This is the body");
message.Body = body;
sc.Send(message);
```

I'v also tried to use 2 sc, called "sc2" with the same parameters of the first, but I receive the same error.
I hope you could help me.
Thank you!
Daniele

Answer (score 0):

When you use `message2.To.Add()` you need to create a new `MailAddress` so your code should be more like `message.To.Add(new MailAddress(address@address.ext));` and the same for `message2`.

I believe that is the problem.  Let me know

EDIT

```
MailMessage message;
string body;
SmtpClient sc;
message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("address@address.ext");
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.smtp.smtp");
sc.Port = 25;
sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("address@address.ext", "password");
sc.EnableSsl = true;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (s, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
message.To.Add("address@address.ext");
message.Subject = "This is the subject";

MailMessage message2;
string body2;
message2 = new MailMessage();
message2.From = new MailAddress("address@address.ext");
message2.IsBodyHtml = true;
message2.To.Add("address@address.ext");
message2.Subject = "This is the subject2";
body2 = "This is the body2"
message2.Body = body2;
sc.Send(message2);

body = "This is the body";
message.Body = body;
sc.Send(message);
```

I changed the body to just be a plain string.

Comment: Now I try! Meanwhile thank you!

Comment: I am going to try to replicate it.

Comment: Try getting rid of the HttpUtility and just writing a plain string as a body as a test.

Comment: Do you mean that I sould'nt use "HttpUtility" for testing?

Comment: No I mean to say, for now pull out the call to HttpUtility, and just use a plain string to pass in as the Body.

Comment: I'm not english, I could misunderstand it... can you show me an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58793/discussion-between-carter-and-daniele-neko-luciani).